# How to send scopes from the google cloud consent screen?

Tags: angular, google-cloud-platform, scope

I selected the scopes in my google cloud app consent screen but it does not appear in the login pop up window. I use Angular for the frontend. Can someone help me to figure out how to code the part to send the scopes to the front.

Here is the plugin i user to login with google:

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: 'SocialAuthServiceConfig',
      useValue: {
        autoLogin: false,
        providers: [
          {
            id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            provider: new GoogleLoginProvider(
              'my secret key'
            )
          }
        ]
      } as SocialAuthServiceConfig,
    },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'fr-FR' }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Why use a plugin? Why not use the Javascript library (this will take care of displaying the scope on the consent screen) - https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/docs/start.md

Comment: I am new to angular and front-end in general, so i would like to implement this the simpliest way. I was able to configure a google signin with google identity  to my app, but i can only get few informations about the user, and a jti token. But the scope i configured in the google cloud consent screen does not appear when signin in and i dont know how to get an access token with scopes. My final purpose is to access gmail api with the users tokens.